# How to push some viewcontrollers with segue at a time

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

When the NavigationController has 3 view controllers (A,B,C).
I want to move to the view controller C from A via B with using a segue at a time.
In this case, what's the best practice?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need perform seque B->C manually once seque A->B is finished (for example in viewDidAppear).

Comment: If the navigation controller has 10 view controllers, do I need to write the code pushing the next view controller at viewDidAppear into all of them?

Comment: Yes. But you can create some base class and program it just one time in ancestor's viewDidAppear.

Comment: Btw. I do not know what app you are programming but can paging scroll be better solution for your needs?

Comment: A is top menu. B is sub menu. C is the menu, too. It's for the business app. And I want to go to C, when receive the remote push notification.

Comment: I see. In that case it is acceptable behaviour to push just C on the stack. When you tap back you return to A. User really do not want to tap back X-times.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [self navigationController];
[navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

I assume you have a segue with appropriate identifier.

Comment: this does not answer the question how to first perform a segue to B and right after to C.

Comment: I want to move to C after moving to B. (A->B->C) Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand the logic to go A-C but moving the way A-B-C.

but this can be done perform seague A-B . in B use the method viewWillAppear() or viewDidload to perform the segue for C .

Hope this will solve your problem.